# How do you safely store an encryption key in .Net?

Tags: .net, encryption, reflector

If you have a .Net application (or any other application for that matter,) how do you safely store internal encryption keys? I'm not talking about user-entered keys, but keys that are hard-coded in the program itself, for talking between other instances of the program. For example, if you have a peer to peer type program, you may want to encrypt the packets so you're sure you're talking to another instance of *your* program, and not someone else's. My solution would be to hard-code a key into the clients, and simply encrypt/decrypt everything that way.

I'm wondering, however, if this is safe to do in .Net. I haven't worked extensively with Reflector or anything of the sort, but from what I hear, it sounds fairly easy to deconstruct .Net applications from CIL. Would going and finding my magic number be trivial for someone with one of these applications?

Comment: You need to look into obfuscation software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to verify that the executable on the other end of the connection is the one you wrote.  If you encrypt a key with a key, where do you store the second key?  If you Diffie-Hellman that with the server's to get a secret key, where do you store that key?  (hint: in memory, where it can be dumped from then read).  It's a recursive problem that you can never solve.

I've read that AOL Instant Messenger's servers would periodically poll the AIM client for the hash of specific addresses of code (i.e. calculate SHA1(address1 -> address2)) and then disconnect the client if the hash was not correct.  This was because it is illegal to redistribute the executable (and unfeasible to build a table of the hash between every two intervals), so this is merely a legal challenge and not a technical one.

If you want software that really tries hard to defeat reverse engineering (and actually does a good job), try attaching a debugger to Skype :-)

Comment: Follow up a year later: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/06/03/open_sourcing_skype/ -- therefore abandon all hope of protecting anything that's distributed to clients :-P  I was very impressed at Skype's effectiveness of anti-reverse-engineering until June of this year.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try putting in your custom encryption/decryption algorithm into a C++ library, then use interop to marshal the data back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding a key, you could generate an asymmetric key (per session?). You can send the public key to a peer, with this key, the peer can encrypt a message that only you can decrypt.

Asymmetric encryption is slow, you the peer could also send a symmetric key encoded with your public key, that is used for this session only.

If you really need to store secret data, you can use the [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class. You could call it during setup, to store your secret (key).

Comment: But would `byte [] secret = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 };` be visible simply by opening up the .exe in Reflector?

Comment: If you put it in another dll and embed that dll in your assembly, it won't open in reflector ... but it could still be extracted and opened.  Protecting in layers and raising the bar of decompiling to a level where most people won't bother is about all you can do with purely managed code.

Comment: How much is your application worth?  I get paid $0/hour at the moment and I'm a beast with debuggers :-)

Comment: Re ProtectedData: reading the class/method documentation, it says the protection relies on the current user account. How would that help, given an application that will be run by other users? If you protected the key while building it under YOUR user account, YOU would be the only one able to retrieve that key / run that software. No other user would be able to correctly run the software, making it useless to distribute. Right?

Comment: @toolmakersteve, You can also use ‘LocalMachine‘ in the scope.

Answer (score 1):

If the key is stored in your program's executable code, or in a resource (or in Windows TCB using a key in the executable code) someone could, with enough effort, decoded it.

Because in the end with the executable they have all the information needed to get it whatever protection you add (since the decoding code is in place as well).

To start with:

- Don't create your own mechanisms, there is too many easy ways to compromise the security (the experts often need multiple tries to get it right).
- Think about the value of what you are trying to protect, and the resources available to those who might attack it. If there is little value to protect you don't need so much protection.
- Unless you are protecting somewhere like [Aldermaston](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_Weapons_Establishment) you don't need *High* *Security*.

The KISS principle will serve you well.